# Specific robust measure of scale

Tags: robust, scale-estimator

Do you know of any outlier resistant measure of scale $R(Y_1, \dots, Y_n)$ with the following property related to the sample standard deviation $S$?

*Magic property:*

If $S(Y_1, \dots, Y_n) > 0, \text{then } R(Y_1, \dots, Y_n) > 0$

IQR and MAD would not do the trick since they are 0 if the distribution is too discrete (but non-constant!)

Or is this impossible?

Answer (score 5):

This is possible in a somewhat artificial sense: just adjust $R$ a little whenever $S$ is nonzero, to guarantee $R$ is nonzero in such cases.

---

"Resistant" means $R$ has a finite breakdown point, but the possibility of a sample with values $(Y, Y, \ldots, Y, Y^\prime \ne Y)$ means that $R$ has to respond to the value of even the most extreme datum. It would seem that such an $R$ could not be resistant.  However, since you have imposed no other conditions on $R$ that might otherwise limit our choices, you could make it resistant by ensuring $R$ cannot change much in such cases.  For example, define it as

$$R(Y_1, \ldots, Y_n) = \text{MAD}(Y_1,\ldots, Y_n) + I(S(Y_1,\ldots,Y_n) \gt 0)/n$$

(using the indicator function $I$).  Because the amount by which this could change the MAD is bounded, $R$ has the same breakdown point as the MAD, making it (strongly) resistant.

This merely adds $1/n$ to the (non-negative) MAD whenever the SD is nonzero, *guaranteeing* the "magic property."  By adding a quantity that decreases to zero as the sample size increases, asymptotically this $R$ will have the same expectation as the MAD, showing that the artificial correction isn't necessarily all that bad.

Of course you would be concerned about all this only when the $Y_i$ do not have a continuous distribution or are strongly correlated (for otherwise the chance of the SD being zero would be nil).

---

If you don't want to bias the estimator relative to the MAD you could, for instance, multiply the MAD by

$$1 + \text{sign}(Y_1-Y_2)I(S(Y_1,\ldots,Y_n)\gt 0)/(2n)$$

when the $Y_i$ are iid.  (This trick obviates the need to use a randomized estimator.)

Naturally the MAD could be replaced by almost any resistant estimator of scale.  The additive factor of $1/n$ could be replaced by any bounded nonzero function of $n$ or the multiplicative factors $1\pm 1/(2n)$ by any function with range in a finite interval $[a,b]$ and $a\gt 0$.

Comment: Any L estimator (linear comb of order statistics) of scale, having nonzero weights, would have the required property.

Comment: @rvl Wouldn't that have zero breakdown point?  In what sense, then, could it be considered "resistant"?

Comment: Good point. Wouldn't be robust. Could probably drum up an adaptive scheme with the L est as starter...

Comment: @whuber: I like your idea very much, thank you. Btw non-zero S just means that not every value is equal. This would make the magic condition look more intuitive.

Comment: This is clever but makes me queasy if you add a view from dimensional analysis. Unless the variable being analysed is itself without dimensions (as a count, for example), adding $1/n$ is adding a quantity with different dimensions and units of measurement. Also, if you change the units of measurement, it's a little messy. My more naive reaction to the question is that such a measure cannot exist universally as even the smallest positive pairwise difference may be unresistant. Example: everything is 7 except for an outlier of 42. So the smallest such difference can equal  the range.

Comment: @Nick I was (elliptically) alluding to such difficulties when I mentioned that the OP had imposed no properties, such as invariance under changes of measurement units. I could dodge that particular problem in several ways, such as by adopting a unit of measure and stipulating that $1/n$ be expressed in terms of it.  I don't think that would add anything to the answer, though.

Comment: Quite. Sometimes we would like to be able to impute what lies beyond the allusions and the ellipses! The plain-speaking answer to the question seems to be "not without bending the rules".

Comment: @Nick I like plain-speaking answers, to be sure: but I don't know what "rules" you might have in mind! As far as I know, I haven't bent any rules for formulating, evaluating, or selecting good statistical procedures. In fact, most of this response was motivated by an effort to point out how the proposed procedure--however strange it might seem--actually *meets* criteria people usually apply to determine good procedures. Although artificial, it's no worse in many respects than other procedures, such as replacing negative estimates of variance (which happens with some estimators) with zeros.

Comment: @whuber I'm being wicked here, as I was playing at allusion too (but at most just expressing a reservation about your solution). But the rules to me imply respect for dimensions and units. I'd want a very good reason to over-ride that in my own work. (Negative variances I think I've seen defended as meaningful, but I have no authority on that kind of issue.)

Comment: @Nick Be wicked all you want--it's a great way to eliminate misconceptions! I feel the way you do about strongly preferring invariant procedures, but I keep running across references to non-invariant procedures working well (especially in the data mining area), so I'm keeping an open mind.

Comment: It's also true that conservatism about dimensions was seriously undermined by Hausdorff, Besicovitch, Mandelbrot, etc. not to mention centuries-old work with power laws or functions $ax^b$ for non-integer $b$.

Comment: @NickCox: I was (and still am) thinking a bit like you in your first comment. Still it looks like a real drawback of IQR and MAD!

Comment: The length of the shortest half can also be zero whenever at least half of the values equal one value. If that sounds unusual, note that anything else is exceptional with binary data (scored 0 and 1, say)!

Answer (score 4):

I will here gather together comments with the import that this is not possible in a simple manner.

Consider an example such as $y = 7, 7, \cdots, 7, 42$ with two distinct values, one of which occurs only once. The singleton in this example, $42$, has outlier flavour. So in broad terms resistant measures of scale are of interest here.

However, as @Michael M points out in the question, for such examples (with positive standard deviation) then IQR and MAD are zero. We could add that so also is the length of the shortest half. But any other alternative to the SD could hardly ignore the value of the smallest pairwise positive difference, i.e. the smallest value of $|y_i - y_j|$ that is positive. Here that is $35$ and for examples of this type it must be equal to the range, and thus quintessentially not robust (or resistant).

Note that for binary data coded $0$ and $1$ similar situations can easily arise, but using the SD as a measure of scale is pretty much universal without discussion. For binary data the IQR and MAD would usually be 0.

Comment: +1. In fact every robust equivariant scale estimator with breakdown at least $m/n$ must be 0 if $m$ observations are tied. This is proven in proposition 1 in *Croux, C.; Filzmoser, P. and Oliveira, M. (2007). Algorithms for Projection-Pursuit Robust Principal Component Analysis.*

Comment: @user603 Thanks; could you add full details for that reference please?

Comment: Yes, it got cut off from the comment: Chemometrics and intelligent laboratory systems, 87 (2), 218-225.

Comment: @user603: perfect! Should it be $n-m$ instead of $m$ tied observations or is it as you state it?

Comment: @MichaelM: yes, n-m!